# How to detect whether a directory is authorized or not?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

In the code below I am checking whether a directory exists or not. I also have to check whether the directory is authenticated or not. How can I do that in ColdFusion?

```
<cfdirectory
    action = "list"
    directory = "#filesystem_query.folderpath#"
    name = "files"
    filter="*.*"
    type="file">
<cfset tot_file=files.recordcount>
<cfdirectory
    action = "list"
    directory = "#filesystem_query.folderpath#"
    name = "files"
    filter=""
    type="dir">
<cfset tot_folder=files.recordcount>
<cfif DirectoryExists(filesystem_query.folderpath)>
    <td>#tot_file#</td>
    <td>#tot_folder# </td>
    <td>#filesystem_query.filetype#</td>
<cfelse>
    <td colspan="3">Path not Exist</td>
</cfif>
```

Comment: If you want people to see your questions, use the [tag:coldfusion] tag as well as the [tag:coldfusion-10] one.

Comment: thanks . hereafter i will use those tag

Comment: Are you looking for ACL information like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html